# Localized MSI setup into Chinese using ORCA tool

Tags: visual-studio-2015, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje, orca

I am editing text into Chinese language of msi setup using orca tool. I generated transform using ORCA in this language and on applied the same to msi setup. Now on running this msi setup the translated values are not corerct. Orca is not able to parse the Chinese characters.

Example: I changed text "Next"  to 关 but on run setup it display as 
[image]

Please help how can i display correct translation using orca.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Installer projects already know Chinese, so do you really need to do this yourself? The project properties window has a Localization pull-down that has two choices of Chinese.

Apart from that, there is a language in the Summary Information that you haven't said you've changed, as well as ProductLanguage in the Property table.

I also suggest that you generate a Chinese MSI with Visual Studio and check the differences. It seems that it might be a fonts issue.

Comment: Actually i need to do it my self, because there are some other language like Vietnamese and this language is not coming in that dropdown. I am facing the same problem with Vietnamese also. So I need to do it manually. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested second paragraph ?

Comment: Yes I changed the product language in the property table. but it didn't work